# wrong PDF output size with ExportAsFixedFormat in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, excel, pdf-generation, excel-2010

I use Excel 2010 with VBA.

I have the following code :

```
mySh.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
mySh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=filePathTmp, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

It generates a PDF without error but the size is not correct.
I get a 22.26 x 28.80 cm instead of the 21.59 x 27.94 cm that I would like to obtain.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have had this issue previously but cannot remember if I fixed it or hacked it. Have you investigated how the zoom affects results?

Comment: I set the zoom to 100% in my PageSetup subroutine. Basically, when I print as PDF using the Excel interface, it works fine but not with ExportAsFixedFormat which is supposed to be a mirror of the Excel functionnality).

Answer (score 8):

I use Excel 2010 and had this problem. I fixed it by changing the printer in Excel's dropdown list on the Print section of the File tab. My default printer is a Konica Minolta copy machine. I changed it to Local Printer (which doesn't actually exist) and it worked! I now have the VBA code returning an 8.5x11 PDF! Now I don't have to use our clunky old laptop with an old Office to get the right size.

Note that picking the Adobe PDF printer did not fix the problem. Just try messing with the different printer choices, or make a fake printer in your computer's Devices and Printers and use that. I hope it works for others with the same issue!

Comment: Xerox 7835 does the same thing. HP 5100, Fax, XPS, OneNote printers don't.

Comment: Just in case, all printers can be found in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices

Comment: Been beating my head against the wall for three days on this one. Setting the default printer to MS XPS or Fax works for me. I've verified it on 4 machines, 3 OSs (WIn 7Pro 64, Server 2008 sp2, Server 2012), 2 versions of Excel (201/2016)

Comment: @SethReuter I'm not completely sure why it works - I think it has something to do with the Windows printer driver.

Comment: Thank You @Crystal, How crazy is that. We will celebrate a 10 year anniversary of that behaviour soon! In Windows 10 the installed printers are to be found in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers`.

Comment: Microsoft found out and describes the [problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/when-exporting-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-pdf-file-the-page-dimensions-may-change-f2f3182d-d8c1-4970-cfec-5d3827ed77f4) without solution. See [question 70656341](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656341/how-to-set-active-printer-to-microsoft-print-to-pdf-without-the-on-xxxx) on how to find printer names on the system.

Answer (score 1):

I set the print area where I wanted it: View-Page Break Preview.
Then File-Print-Scaling = Fit Sheet on One Page
Or
File-Print-Page Setup-Fit to: 1 pages wide by 1 tall.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Excel 2010 and had the same problem. When using ExportAsFixedFormat, the page won't scale. From what I understand, it is the same as using the Save As with file type pdf. This means that you need to need to scale your workbook to fit the page that you require.

If you:

-Open printer settings and select 'No Scaling'

-Page Layout > Print Area > Clear Print Area

-Select View > Page Break View

It will show you the page area. If you scale your worksheet to this it will save to pdf using ExportAsFixedFormat properly.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problema and soved it changing at devices and printers the default printing options:

-Control Panel->Devices and Printers->Select the printer by clicking once to it.

-Second mouse button->Printer properties->Advanced->Printing defaults->Advanced.

-Choose paper size and click OK.

Why not to change it at excel? Because somthing related to permissions between Excel and the service running spool or...

That default setting makes the macro to export to the paper size correctly.

If it Works for you, is thanks to our IT department, not to me :P