# Converting multiple sheet Excel file to PDF using VBA error

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I am currently trying to convert a multiple sheet excel file to a PDF using VBA using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim mySheets As Variant, sh

mySheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
For Each sh In mySheets
    Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
Next

Sheets(mySheets).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="S:\GasInc\Services\B&ITS\OpsEng\EngServ\_Station Design\Projects\Station Co-ops\Angela Lian" & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

It converts my file fine, however for what I have on sheet 2 it splits it up into multiple pages in the PDF because I guess it does not scale it to fit the page. I was wondering how I could modify the code to make it scale this sheet so it will fit on one page of the PDF.

Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32003276/4088852).  You'll basically have to check the first member of `.VPageBreaks`, calculate the width to the first break, and then scale to fit the page break.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar sub in one of the tools I use.  Do you have your worksheet's width / height scale to fit properties set to 1 page?

```
For Each sh In mySheets
    With Sheets(sh).PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
Next sh
```

One of the weird things I've run into is scaling issues when converting to PDF with some chart / image objects.  For instance a logo looks fine on screen but prints stretched on the pdf.  I never fixed the problem, but through research it seemed due to the way the printer sees it compared to the screen resolution.  Have you ever run into that problem?