# How to set active printer to microsoft print to pdf without the "on XXXX:"

Tags: vba

I'm needing to set my printer to "Microsoft Print to PDF" but how would I know which port it will be on? It could be different on another machine. I need to it to be able to set it without knowing the port "on XXXX:" part like this:

```
Application.activeprinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
?ActivePrinter 'show active printer "XXXXXX on XXXX:"
```

Comment: @KJ my port is "Ne03" is that a default port on everyone's or does everyone have different ports for Microsoft Print to PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The simplest way:

Try manually printing (anything) from Excel on the above printer.

Then use the next code line: `Debug.Print Application.ActivePrinter`. It will return in `Immediate Window` the printer name string (port included) to be used in case of setting it as Active.

2. The next code returns the printer with its port, being called with printer name as argument:

```
Function FindPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String
  Dim arrH, Pr, Printers, Printer As String
  Dim RegObj As Object, RegValue As String
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
       
    Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    RegObj.Enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Printers, arrH
    
      For Each Pr In Printers
        RegObj.getstringvalue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Pr, RegValue
        Printer = Pr & " on " & Split(RegValue, ",")(1)
        If InStr(1, Printer, PrinterName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           FindPrinter = Printer
           Exit Function
        End If
      Next
End Function
```

It can be called in the next way:

```
Sub testFindPrinter()
    Debug.Print Application.ActivePrinter
    Debug.Print FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")
End Sub
```

Or, simple set the active printer in the next way:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")
```

**Edited**:

I did not know that the suffix before the printer port should/can be regionalized. Thanks to @T.M. I know now. In such a case the function can be updated with the next way of this suffix string extraction:

```
   Dim suff As String, arrSuff
   arrSuff = Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " ")
   suff = arrSuff(UBound(arrSuff) - 1)
```

Comment: I just wish i can set the printer like this Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF" so that i don't have to look up the printer. What if there's an error trying to find printer using the above function like permission access etc?

Comment: @VKid I also wish to look in my bank account and see what Bill Gates sees... But, since it is necessary to use the port included in the string, you should use the above function and do what you want as: `Application.ActivePrinter = FindPrinter("Microsoft Print to PDF")`, as I completed in my above edited answer...

Comment: @VKid "The above function" cannot raise any error. It extracts values from a specific Registry key and builds the necessary string to be used when try setting the active printer...

Comment: will the registry key Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    RegObj.Enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Printers, arrH be the same for any users?

Comment: @VKid It will be computer specific, according to the installed printers. It will return the correct printer (port included) for the computer where the code runs. The code will return the appropriate printer name, in any case.

Comment: @FaneDuru Seems that the `Application.ActivePrinter` suffix "... **on** XXX:" depends on regional language settings (e.g. output in German is "... *auf** XXX:"), whereas the `FindPrinter` function expects the system wide (English) input with **"on"**. Btw Nice post +:)

Comment: @T.M. Didn't know anything about suffix regionalization.  It can be easily extracted using something like: `Dim suff As String, arrSuff: arrSuff = Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " ")` followed by `suff = arrSuff(UBound(arrSuff) - 1)`. In fact, I will edit the answer and add such a code for the case of different because of regionalization.