# Setting a network printer as the active printer in a Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to print out a workbook where each sheet is a separate page and only printed on one side. The rest of the macro seems ok however on line     currentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter I get Run-time error 1004. Method 'ActivePrinter' of object '_application' failed. I have checked the network settings and running as administrator and that works fine so I believe the problem lies with the code

```
Sub Print1sided()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim currentPrinter As String
    Dim printerName As String

    printerName = "\\SERVER\PRINTER-NAME"

    currentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter

    Application.ActivePrinter = printerName

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

        ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
        ws.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
        ws.PageSetup.Order = xlOverThenDown
        ws.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600 ' Set print quality (adjust as needed)
        ws.PageSetup.Duplex = xlDuplexSimplex ' Set to one-sided (simplex)

        ws.PrintOut
    Next ws

End Sub
type here
```

I have tried setting the active printer as the network path directly and this still didn't work.

Comment: You need the port information on the end - eg `printerName = "\\SERVER\PRINTER-NAME on Ne01:"`

Comment: c.f. [How to set active printer to ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656341/how-to-set-active-printer-to-microsoft-print-to-pdf-without-the-on-xxxx/70656871#70656871)

Comment: Try this solution, I believe it will work correctly. [How to set active printer to microsoft print to pdf without the "on XXXX:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656341/how-to-set-active-printer-to-microsoft-print-to-pdf-without-the-on-xxxx/70656871#70656871)

Comment: Think this to be the same site, but same idea :-; @Romssnes

Comment: Thanks for your help! however no of these comments fix the issue leading me to believe it is a network issue rather than a VBA issue.